# mySQL won't create table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, innodb

I have it set up to echo when my tables create but the users table just won't, I've looked at multiple solutions but none of them has helped here my code

```
<? 
    phpinclude_once("index.php");
    $tbl_users = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users 
                  (
                      id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
                      username VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL,
                      email VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
                      password VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
                      gender ENUM('m','f') NOT NULL,
                      website VARCHAR(64) NULL,
                      country VARCHAR(64) NULL,
                      userlevel ENUM('a','b','c','d') NOT NULL DEFAULT a,
                      avatar VARCHAR(64) NULL,
                      ip VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
                      signup DATETIME NOT NULL,
                      lastlogin DATETIME NOT NULL,
                      notescheck DATETIME NOT NULL,
                      activated ENUM('0','1') NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
                      PRIMARY KEY (id)),
                      UNIQUE KEY username (username,email))";
    $query = mysqli_query($db_spooky, $tbl_users);

    if ($query === TRUE)
    {
        echo "<h3>user table created OK :) </h3>";
    }
    else 
    {
        echo "<h3>user table NOT created :( </h3>";
    }
?>
```

Comment: whats the error ?

Comment: Please properly format your code. It's hard to read, and it introduces syntax errors.

Comment: You have too many close parenthesis in your query.

Comment: Please try to describe a little more clearly what you are expecting your code to do and in which way it fails to do what you expect. Posting some output, like an error message could be helpful, too.

Comment: Multiple users can have the same `username`??  (As long as they have different emails.)

Comment: When a query fails, you should check for the error. This can help you troubleshoot on your own. See http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
                                  ,username VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL
                                  ,email VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,password VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL
                                  ,gender ENUM('m','f') NOT NULL
                                  ,website VARCHAR(64) NULL
                                  ,country VARCHAR(64) NULL
                                  ,userlevel ENUM('a','b','c','d') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'a'
                                  ,avatar VARCHAR(64) NULL
                                  ,ip VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL
                                  ,signup DATETIME NOT NULL
                                  ,lastlogin DATETIME NOT NULL
                                  ,notescheck DATETIME NOT NULL,activated ENUM('0','1') NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
                                  ,PRIMARY KEY (id)
                                  ,UNIQUE KEY username (username,email))
```

Learn to organize your code instead of writing it in one long line for one, and two, ENUM default for a needs to be in single quotes and you had an extra closing bracket. The code above is the corrected version.

Comment: I usually recommend against ENUM altogether. References to (relatively) static lookup tables are much better, and don't require an alter table (necessitating the entire table be recreated "behind the scenes") when a new value is added. You touch on the other issue with ENUM in your remark about the default; `DEFAULT 0` was "acceptable"... and would've been so for the `userlevel` and `gender` fields too, resulting in the default being the value at index 0 in the enum lists... could/would cause some major confusion in `activated` if it was declared as `ENUM('1','0')` though.